# How to interpolate a multivariate model from several discrete lines

Tags: python, model, interpolation, linear-algebra

I'm working on a data project in python at the moment, but I got stuck trying to create a multivariate model.

Essentially I need to model a deterministic relationship in the form f(w,x,y) = z from discrete data. Data collection is relatively time consuming, but I can collect any point z given (w,x,y), such that {z,w,x,y ε R+}

So far I have modelled z(w=0,x,y) using scipy's interp2d by collecting discrete points about 3 lines:

```
   l1 = z(0,h,0)
   l2 = z(0,0,h)
   l3 = z(0,h,h)
```

where {hεR+|h<7}. I sampled more points around the origin because I wanted more resolution down there.

I'm looking for guidance on what is the most efficient way to model this on higher order models. Currently my next step is obviously 4-D, but an ideal solution applies to the nth dimension. I'm considering putting together a small NN; Resources aren't a concern when building/training the model, but I should keep compute power in mind for using it as this model is

Basically my questions are 1. What is the most efficient sampling technique? 2. What library would serve best?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Scipy multivariate interpolation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html)?

Scipy is usually the first (and mostly the best) choice.